# Local Security Policies, System Group Policy Objects, and Active Directory values not updating Secedit.exe Sec.cfg

Tags: active-directory, registry, windows-server-2016, group-policy, security-policy

I am attempting to monitor the status of SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege and SeEnableDelegationPrivilege to determine if they have been updated/changed. When doing so, this configuration file doesn't seem to update. Are there any other locations where a variable would affect "Force shutdown form a remote system" and "Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation". I have already looked through Microsoft Registry key documentation. Here's the link I referred to: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250  I have looked into using Get-GPRegistryValue, Get-GPOReport, and Get-GPO. The way I generated Sec.cfg was using "Secedit /export /cfg sec.cfg /log NUL".

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Hey @user18638085, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   For the **‘Force Shutdown from a Remote System’** setting to apply effectively on a client system, kindly check whether the below group policy regarding this setting has been applied or not by executing the command **‘gpresult /h gpreport.html’** on the elevated command prompt on the client system. In the report, please check whether the above said group policy setting has been applied successfully or not.

Group policy setting: -

On the Group Policy Server, check the below group policy setting by checking the **‘Default domain policy’** or that policy which controls the below setting: -

```
  Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment/Force shutdown from a remote system
```

To forcefully apply the domain group policy settings on the client system, execute the command **‘gpupdate /force’** on an elevated command prompt and restart the client system. Then check the client’s group policy report once again to check whether the setting has been applied or not.

•   Also, I would suggest you to please make the above said modifications on a baseline client system through local group policy editor and export the settings in an **‘.inf’** template for installation via **powershell script**. Check for the below settings information in the ‘.inf’ file and then execute the below command by modifying the values for ‘.inf’ file and **‘.db’** file as appropriate: -

```
 [Privilege Rights]
 SeDenyServiceLogonRight = *S-1-1-0,*S-1-5-19, Administrators

 secedit.exe /configure /cfg C:\customsettings.inf /db C:\WINDOWS\security\Database\customsettings.db /quiet
```

By doing the above, your issue should get resolved.